# How to manage logged in user page header

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How is something like the header on stack overflow managed in a Java servlet? If you are logged in the header is different to if you are not but you can still search and use the site.

I am currently dispatching requests to my various request handlers via a single servlet, these request handlers in turn forward to a JSP; do I have to implement logic in each request handler that sets an attribute signalling whether or not a user is logged in and then an `if` `else` `JSTL` block in the JSP or something? Is there any way to manage this in the controller servlet?

All the patterns I have seen for managing a logged in user seem to resort to a redirection to a login/register page, but I don't want an all or nothing system forcing users to login to use the site, just a different header like stack overflow.

Comment: Do you have User roles setup already? It sounds like your using spring, do you have spring security setup?

Comment: @ns47731 I'm just using plain servlets in Tomcat. I am working on user functionality now, haven't set up much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a place to store user information, I would get a database setup and use something like Hibernate. Then you need a way to use that information to designate users and allow then to login, I would recommend Spring Security. My personal favorite website to get tutorials/guides for both of these frameworks is Mkyong. Heres one on spring security http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/

Here is a code sample of getting the authenticaed user from a project I have worked on, this example has a User Object that is retrived from a database.

```
public static User currentUser() {
    if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext() != null && 
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null && 
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() != null &&
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() instanceof User) {
        //logger.debug(className, "currentUser", "User: " + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
        return (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the Jsp it would read something like this

```
<c:if test="${esFn:currentUser() not null}">Your logged in!!!</c:if>
```

esFn is a function defined in the functions.tld like this

```
<function>
    <name>currentUser</name>
    <function-class>com.test.User</function-class>
    <function-signature>
        com.test.User currentUser()
    </function-signature>
</function>
```